# Can't call method "disconnect" without a package..Perl

Tags: perl, module, dbi

I wrote a perl module:

```
package sql;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(DBImport DataFill);
our @EXPORT = qw(DBImport DataFill);

our $dbh;

sub DBConnect() {
    my $platform = "mysql";
    my $database = "databasename";
    my $host = "localhost";
    my $user = "user";
    my $pw = "password";
    my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:$database:localhost";
    $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw);
    $dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8');
    return $dbh;
}

sub Query($) {
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(shift);
    $sth->execute;
    while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
        print $ref->{'email'};
    }
    $sth->finish();
}

BEGIN{
    $dbh = &DBConnect();
}

END{
    $dbh->disconnect();
}
1;
```

and i tried use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser/;
use sql;

&Query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

but it don't working.

error message: Undefined subroutine &main::Query called at /var/www/domains/gabordx.tauri.hu/www/main.pl line 7. -> "&Query("SELECT * FROM users");"

What is the problem with?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that all-lowercase module names are [usually reserved for pragmas](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html#Guidelines-for-Module-Creation).  Additionally, you don't need to import DBD::mysql explicitly, since `DBI->connect()` will load the right driver for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export `Query` as well, like this:

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(Query DBImport DataFill);
our @EXPORT = qw(Query DBImport DataFill);
```

Otherwise you should refer it through `sql` package, like this

```
sql::Query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call it directly, prepending module name:

```
sql::Query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

or you can import it from the module

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(Query DBImport DataFill); # In the module

use sql qw(Query); # In caller code
```

or you can export it by default from sql.pm

```
our @EXPORT = qw(Query DBImport DataFill);
```

Reference for `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK`: http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#How-to-Export

Answer (score 0):

One way is to export the function:

```
our @EXPORT = qw(DBImport DataFill Query);
```

[perldoc Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)